# Yii Creating an audit trail; Controller to another Controller

Tags: php, function, yii, controller, audit

I'm creating an audit trail module for a project using Yii php, and i'm quite a newbi.. and as we all know audit trail is concerned with the creation of history, transaction logs... i've created a model for the audit trail
and generated a controller as well as a separate model for it. (Using gii of course)

My problem lies with how to actually create an entry , or a trail (log, history, i don't know the term sorry =3)

I have my AuditTrailController with an action:

```
class AuditTrailController extends Controller{

    public function actionCreate()
    {
    //do create the trail   
    }

}
```

My plan is to call the actionCreate() from every other controllers from all over the modules in the whole project like say:

```
class StudyController extends Controller {

        public function addRecord(){
        //add some record


        //---> i want to call the acionCreate() from the AuditTrailController from here
        //to create an entry telling that the some user "user" at time "time"
        //performed an "add" operation..
        }

        public function updateRecord(){
        //update some record


        //---> i want to call the acionCreate() from the AuditTrailController from here
        //create an audit entry telling the user "updated"
        }

}
```

-The Yii:app() doesn't do the trick..(or ive used it wrongly)..

I've searched for many answers but they say it's "evil" to call another controller from one..i saw terms like using Component..other say it should be done in the model... but i have no idea.. i'm new in OOP and Yii so i'm in a struggle here.. help me out thanks.. but if the above is possible then a sample code would be really helpful thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call action in another controller in this way

//here is you controller with action

```
class AuditTrailController extends Controller
{

    public function actionCreate()
    {
    //do create the trail   
    }

}
```

//here controller where you want to use your action

```
class StudyController extends Controller {

        public function addRecord(){
               $controller = new AuditTrailController($this->id);
               $controller->actionCreate();
        }
}
```

And don't forget add to config this line to import

```
    'application.controllers.*',
```

Comment: error shows No such file or directory;
i forgot to tell you ... the two controllers are in separate modules..

say: module 1 contains audittrailcontroller, and module 2 contains the studycontroller..thanks

so i'm kinda guessing the studycontroller class cannot find the other class so that the "new AuditTrailController()" doesnt work

Comment: i'm basically creating a module called "audit" to keep track of the actions of a specific user's transactions throughout the system, so i'm really expecting modules from all throughout the project to work with the audit module calling atleast its actionCreate() to produce a log

Comment: in your module directory file yournameModule.php, function Init(), add to $this->setImport, location of you controller from another module, like 'audit(name of your module).controllers.*',